# Swift Does not conform to protocol error adopting Objective C Protocol

Tags: objective-c, swift, protocols

I keep getting the "Type does not conform to protocol" error when trying to adopt an objective-c protocol in my swift code. I am implementing all the required methods, but the compiler gives an error for each of the methods.

The protocol declaration in the Objective-C file is

```
@protocol RBLProtocolDelegate
-(void) protocolDidReceiveCustomData:(uint8_t *) data length:(uint8_t) length;
-(void) protocolDidReceiveProtocolVersion:(UInt8) major Minor:(UInt8) minor Bugfix:(UInt8) bugfix;
-(void) protocolDidReceiveTotalPinCount:(uint8_t) count;
-(void) protocolDidReceivePinCapability:(uint8_t) pin Value:(uint8_t) value;
-(void) protocolDidReceivePinMode:(uint8_t) pin Mode:(uint8_t) mode; /* mode: I/O/Analog/PWM/Servo */

-(void) protocolDidReceivePinData:(uint8_t) pin Mode:(uint8_t) mode Value:(uint8_t) value;
@end
```

In my swift file I have (this is just one of the methods, I have implemented all the others as well, but I am just showing one for brevity's sake)

```
 @objc func protocolDidReceiveProtocolVersion(major: UInt8, minor: UInt8, bugfix: UInt8) {

}
```

which yields the compiler error:

> Objective-C method 'protocolDidReceiveProtocolVersion:minor:bugfix:'
>   provided by method
>   'protocolDidReceiveProtocolVersion(_:minor:bugfix:)' does not match
>   the requirement's selector
>   ('protocolDidReceiveProtocolVersion:Minor:Bugfix:')

[Screenshot of issue in xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5CQb.png)

Comment: This seems to be a bug. As in the referenced "duplicate", you can work around the problem by annotating the Swift method with the exact Objective-C selector, in your case `@objc(protocolDidReceiveProtocolVersion:Minor:Bugfix:)`.

Comment: Thanks Martin! Sorry about the duplicate question, I did search stack overflow first, but somehow missed that duplicate question. How did you know about the ability to annotate functions with the objective-c selector? I don't remember seeing it in the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" documentation

Comment: See "Language Reference -> Attributes" in the Swift book: The objc attribute optionally accepts a single attribute argument, which consists of an identifier. Use this attribute when you want to expose a different name to Objective-C for the entity the objc attribute applies to.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a case-sensitivity issue. Your protocol declares

```
protocolDidReceiveProtocolVersion:Minor:Bugfix:
```

And you are implementing:

```
protocolDidReceiveProtocolVersion:minor:bugfix:
```

Note the lower case 'm' and 'b' in your version.

Edit: It actually looks like Xcode autocompletes the protocol implementation incorrectly in Swift. The only way I can get it to behave is to modify the Objective-C protocol definition to use a lower-case 'M' and 'B' for those argument names.

Even the trivial test Objective-C protocol:

```
@protocol FooProtocol
- (void)foo:(NSInteger)foo Bar:(NSInteger)bar;
@end
```

Seems not possible to implement in Swift due to the uppercase 'B' on 'Bar'. I haven't read about this behaviour with protocols, and it seems like a major oversight. Perhaps file a radar with Apple?